# cycles transparent image textures in lookdev (blender 2.8)

Tags: texturing

I am wondering how to make transparent textures work in the lookdev mode.

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

This is what I want (blender 2.79 material mode):
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution

You need to first switch the render engine to Eevee, go into the shader editor, and now you will see a setting to change the blend mode to Alpha Blend. Now it will work in lookdev and you can change it back to cycles.

[image]